# memoryleak in gridview using base adapter and viewholder method

Tags: android, gridview, memory-leaks, baseadapter

I am using an extended `BaseAdapter` for my gridview in which I implement `ViewHolder` methods. also I pass my data with a Cursor to this adapter.

here is my `getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {    // inflate the layout for each item of listView

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(gridItemId, null);
            Log.d("recyvleView", "inflating " + position);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvAttachment = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_inventory_products_griditems_attachment);
            holder.imageCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagecount);
            holder.tvItemCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_ItemCode);
            holder.tvProductName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Title);
            holder.tvPrice = (RialTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Price);
            holder.tvRemain = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Remain);
            holder.btnMore =(com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_More);
            holder.btnPlus = (com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_addOne);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            Log.d("recyvleView", "restoring " + position);
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        setupView(view, position,holder);


        //setupGridView(view,holder);


        return view;
    }
```

I noticed that I have a huge memory leak in this so I tried to minimize everything to find the leak, so I commented most of the methods and here is what has been left from my `setupView`:

```
private void setupView(View view, int position, ViewHolder holder) {

        // move the cursor to required position

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Log.d("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));


        //holder.itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEM_ID.toString()));
        //TSimpleProduct tempProduct = productCatalog.getSimpleProductById(Integer.parseInt(holder.itemId));
        //holder.itemGuId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_GUID.toString()));
        holder.tvItemCode.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMCODE.toString())));
        holder.tvProductName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMDESC.toString())));

      /*  //Remain
        if (cyberSetting.getSettingValue(TCyberSettingKey.SHOWITEMREMAIN).equals("1")) {
            textTemp = (mContext.getString(R.string.restrictedInfo));
        } else {
            if (tempProduct.getDefaultUnitValue() == 2 && tempProduct.isUnitDependent()) {
                String titleRemain2 = DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_CURSOR_REMAIN2.toString();
                textTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(titleRemain2));
            }
            if (cyberSetting.getSettingValue(TCyberSettingKey.SHOWITEMREMAIN).equals("2")) {
                if (textTemp == null) {
                    textTemp = "0";
                }
                int t = Integer.parseInt(textTemp);
                if (t > 0) {
                    textTemp = mContext.getString(R.string.productAvailable);
                } else {
                    textTemp = mContext.getString(R.string.productUnAvailable);
                }
            }
        }
        holder.tvRemain.setText(textTemp);

        //Price
        String priceLevel = "0";
        try {
            Register register = Register.getInstance();
            priceLevel = register.getPriceLevel();
        } catch (NoDaoSetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!priceLevel.equals("0"))
            textTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(priceLevel));
        else
            textTemp = "0.0";

        if (tempProduct.getDefaultUnitValue() == 2 && tempProduct.isUnitDependent()) {
            double price2;
            price2 = TLineItem.convertPrice1ToPrice2(Double.parseDouble(textTemp), tempProduct.isUnit1Bigger(), tempProduct.getUnitCoef());
            textTemp = TGeneralTools.ConvertDoubleToEnglishString(price2);
            if (tempProduct.getUnitDesc2() != null && !tempProduct.getUnitDesc2().equals(""))
                unitDesc = " (" + tempProduct.getCompleteUnitDesc2() + ")";
        } else {
            if (tempProduct.getUnitDesc1() != null && !tempProduct.getUnitDesc1().equals(""))
                unitDesc = " (" + tempProduct.getCompleteUnitDesc1() + ")";
        }
        holder.priceDef = textTemp;
        holder.tvPrice.setText(textTemp + unitDesc);

        holder.tvRemain.setText(holder.tvRemain.getText() + unitDesc);


        //image
        pictureCatalog = TPictureCatalog.getInstance();
        String defGuid = "";

        if (tempProduct.getHasAttachContent() >= 1 && pictureCatalog.isDownloadedAlbumAvailable()) {
            defGuid = pictureCatalog.getDefaultPictureGuid(holder.itemGuId);
            if (tempProduct.getHasAttachContent() == 1) {
                holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageCount.setText(String.valueOf(tempProduct.getHasAttachContent()));
            }
        } else {
            holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + FileAddressContent.APPLICATION_HOME_DIRECTORY
                + FileAddressContent.PICTURES_ROOT_DIRECTORY
                //+ FileAddressContent.PICTURES_THUMBS_DIRECTORY.toString()
                + defGuid + FileAddressContent.PICTURES_EXTENSION;
        pic = new File(filename);
        if (pic.exists())
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(pic)
                    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
                            //.placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .resize(thumbSize, thumbSize)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(holder.tvAttachment);
        else
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.noimage)
                    .resize(thumbSize, thumbSize)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(holder.tvAttachment);
        holder.tvAttachment.setMinimumHeight(thumbSize);


        view.setTag(holder);*/

    }
```

even though almost all of it is commented, these two lines are still leaking, I know cause when I commented them out, no leak was there ... !

```
 holder.tvItemCode.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMCODE.toString())));
        holder.tvProductName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMDESC.toString())));
```

also this is my holder class :

```
public class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView tvAttachment;
    public ImageView ivStatus;
    public TextView imageCount;
    public TextView tvItemCode;
    public TextView tvProductName;
    public TextView tvRemain;
    public RialTextView tvPrice;

    public String priceDef;
    public String itemId;
    public String itemGuId;
    public Button btnMore;
    public Button btnPlus;

}
```

any suggestion, please ?! how can I stop it from leaking ?!
thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I get same result using cursor adapter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `BaseAdapter`? Android API has [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) which handles all the cursor stuff. Looks like you are doing something wrong with cursors and this causes memory leaks.

Comment: got same result with `cursoradapter` as well